Why can I not see my c drive in msys2 with ls -la?
In MSYS2 the windows c drives gets mounted to the filesystem root at /c with the command cd /c I can change into the directory. However, the directory is not visible when I run the command ls -la /. What's the deal here? I googled around and couldn't find any satisfactory answer. And it seems a lot of other people have come across this oddity
e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376899/how-do-i-navigate-my-windows-folders-like-c-drive-in-msys#comment84107651_11376918

This is most likely better answered by people who have low level knowledge of msys or even what I believe be "the source"; cygwin -> try www.cygwin.com

Seems like this is because of implementation details of cygwin. There is an open issue on github: https://github.com/msys2/msys2-runtime/issues/195
